# Why is the shape of multidimensional arrays handled differently in numpy when using axis parameter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, axis

I am a rookie in the python language and have a question regarding the shape of arrays.
So far as I understand, if a 3 dimensional numpy array is created like this
`temp = numpy.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]], [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8]]])`,
the shape is created like in the following figure:
[shape of 3 dimensional array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hadmT.png)
To calculate the sum, median etc. an axis can be defined to calculate the values e.g.

```
>>> print(numpy.median(temp, axis=0))
[[3. 3. 3.] [4. 4. 4.] [5. 5. 5.]]
>>> print(numpy.median(temp, axis=1))
[[1. 1. 1.] [4. 4. 4.] [7. 7. 7.]]
>>> print(numpy.median(temp, axis=2))
[[0. 1. 2.] [3. 4. 5.] [6. 7. 8.]]
```

which implies to me a shape like this [shape of 3 dimensional array using axis parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkqgS.png)
Why is the shape handled differently when calculateing the sum, median etc.with the axis parameter?

Comment: I'd suggest you make a 3d array like `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)` and try this same 3 medians.  Look  at the values as well as the resulting shape.  The effect of `sum` might be easier to see than `median`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numpy array `temp = numpy.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]], [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8]]])` looks actually like this:

```
     axis=2
       |
       v
[[[0 0 0]  <-axis=1
  [1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]] <- axis=0

 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]
  [5 5 5]]

 [[6 6 6]
  [7 7 7]
  [8 8 8]]]
```

Therefore, when you take the median over specific axis, numpy keeps the rest of the axis as is and finds the median along the specified axis. To have a better understanding, I am going to use the suggested array in comments by @hpaulj:

temp:

```
     axis=2
       |
       v
[[[ 0  1  2  3] <-axis=1
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]] <- axis=0

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]
```

We then have:

```
numpy.median(temp, axis=0):

#The first element is median of [0,12], second one median of [1,13] and so on.
[[ 6.  7.  8.  9.]
 [10. 11. 12. 13.]
 [14. 15. 16. 17.]]


np.median(temp, axis=1)

#The first element is median of [0,4,8], second one median of [1,5,9] and so on.
[[ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [16. 17. 18. 19.]]


np.median(temp, axis=2)

#The first element is median of [0,1,2,3], second one median of [4,5,6,7] and so on.
[[ 1.5  5.5  9.5]
 [13.5 17.5 21.5]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess that I understand the meaning of the axis paramter now. The axis parameter defines/numbers the **index** on which the value is calculated.

The term `np.sum(temp, axis=0)` is equivalent to:
`[[temp[0][0][0]+temp[1][0][0], temp[0][0][1]+temp[1][0][1], temp[0][0][2]+temp[1][0][2], temp[0][0][3]+temp[1][0][3]],[..], [...] ...]`

The term `np.sum(temp, axis=1)` is equivalent to:
`[[[temp[0][0][0]+temp[0][1][0]+temp[0][2][0], temp[0][0][1]+temp[0][1][1]+temp[0][2][1], temp[0][0][2]+temp[0][1][2]+temp[0][2][2], temp[0][0][3]+temp[0][1][3]+temp[0][2][3]], [...]]`